# Print Set in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to print set in the order (8,9,5,2,6,4,3).But instead of printing in this order it gets printed in this order (9, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4, 8).Why does it so?

```
object Main 

{

   def main(args: Array[String])

   {

      val fruit = scala.collection.mutable.Set(8,9,8,5,2,6,4,3,5)

      println( "fruit1.++(fruit2) : " + fruit )

     }

}
```

Comment: You want a [LinkedHashSet](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet) if you wish to maintain insertion order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sets are traditionally unordered, so the insertion order of elements is usually lost. List are ordered, but differ from Sets in that they can have duplicate elements.

You'll want to use a [LinkedHashSet](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet) if you wish to use a Set that maintains insertion order when iterating over its elements.

Warning: LinkedHashSet is mutable, [ListSet](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.ListSet) is an immutable option that stores the reverse of the insertion ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Sets are not sorted inherently, but can you use a [SortedSet](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0/index.html#scala.collection.SortedSet)? There is some decent documentation on sets [on the scala webpage.](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/sets.html)

Comment: :But what if I have to print the set t(8,9,8,5,2,6,4,3,5) in this order (8,9,5,2,6,4,3)(that is in the order of its first occurence)?

Comment: I would use a List type and check for the existence of the element before adding it to the list. If it's there, don't add it.

Answer (score 1):

Set is an unordered data type. Use an ordered set - such as SortedSet or TreeSet - and pass it a customized sorting algorithm to sort based on when it was added to the set.

You will have to create your own data type which holds the integer value you're trying to store and a date attribute representing the entry time.

**Another option**
You could use an ArrayList or some other list type. And instead of directly adding an element, call your own add method which checks to see if the element is there already with the contains method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: :ArrayList is not present in Scala.

Comment: Any list type will do, or you could use the Java ArrayList.